# How to change SCSS Variables from Root Variable CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I was going to change this scss variable from a root variable like this

```
:root {
    --primary-custom : yellow;
    --primary-hover-custom : blue;
}

$primary:                                           var(--primary-custom);
$primary-hover:                                     var(--primary-hover-custom);
```

but it returns this error:

`` Argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color ``

What is the best approach to do this, I want to use this `--primary-custom` so I could change it dynamically with javascript like this:

```
const root = document.documentElement;
root.style.setProperty("--primary-custom", lightColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can’t. Information doesn’t flow in that direction.

SASS is compiled to CSS (usually at build time) and then the resulting CSS is sent to the browser.

You can’t pass CSS variables back to SASS because it is too late and probably on the wrong computer.

——-

I’d probably approach this problem by using classes instead of CSS variables and having the colour schemes predefined in the SASS.

`@each` could help by looping over the colour schemes.